# Angular 2 - pdf opened in new tab is always blank

Tags: angular, pdf, hyperlink

I am trying to link to a local PDF file via standard `<a>` tag. Somehow all PDFs that it opens are completely blank - although it correctly opens the new tab and also loads the corresponding file for the link.

```html
<a *ngIf="hasPDF()" href="assets/pdf/{{productId}}.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a>
```

If I add it as a download link, it will download the file and correctly display its content text.

```html
<a *ngIf="hasPDF()" href="assets/pdf/{{productId}}.pdf" download>PDF</a>
```

Getting the same behaviour among Chrome/FF/IE.